# Relative expense of vertex processing vs pixel shading

Tags: directx, shader

A directX application I'm about to develop could be implemented in two ways - one where we have a large number of triangles with associated colors, and one where we have a smaller number of triangles but add detail by texture mapping from generated textures.

I'm new enough to GPU hardware that I don't have an intuition for the expense of these two approaches - my guess is that the processing large numbers of vertices is more expensive than a small number of vertices but with some detail added from pixel shaders, but can't really justify that in terms of hardware.

Could anyone explain how to think about this or if this is even the right mindset?

Any help appreciated

Anondev

Comment: Look at how games did and do handle this. They use techniques such as bump mapping to fake a lower polygon count. I think your logic is correct in that you want to be conservative with your polygons. If I were you I would ask myself if I could get away with a shader and if that's not good enough than use more polygons.

Answer (score 0):

It is more efficient to use large polygons and detail them using textures.  That is why texture mapping exists.  It is an attempt to make a flat surface appear more detailed.  Bump mapping techniques further enhance the effect by making lighting behave as though the polygon is not flat.

However this will never look as realistic as using polygons, because of problems such as silouette being flat etc.

If you imagine triangles so small that they end up taking up one pixel on the screen.  Each pixel will have had to have had its position calculated using matrix maths, each polygon will have been handed to the rasteriser and converted into a single pixel, each pixel will be sent to the pixel shader.  This is a lot of work and the pixel shader still has to run to work out the lighting for this pixel.

If instead we have one large triangle filling the screen, only three vertices are translated using matrix maths, the rasteriser converts one triangle into pixels.  The pixel shader is executed the same number of times as in the previous example.  The only difference is the pixel shader needs to make a texture map lookup, which is relatively inexpensive.

Comment: thanks - small follow-up question - if you want to texture a quad, would it not be more efficient to texture a square subregion of a single triangle instead?

Comment: @AnonDev - this can depend on the hardware. I would tend towards the single triangle as this won't introduce the corner-to-corner diagonal in which pixel groups are partially rasterised up to the edge from both sides.